# Pass array with formdata in ajax

Tags: python, jquery, django, ajax

I want ajax to post form data as well as an array but when I pass array it displays none or empty.

```
jQuery("#myform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'urlAjax' %}',
            data: formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
               alert("Success");
            }
        });
    });
```

I am able to fetch formdata in django views but I also want to fetch an array.
I tried using:

```
jQuery("#myform").submit(function (e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        arr = ['My', 'Array'];
        var formData = new FormData(this);
        formData.append('arr[]': arr);
        jQuery.ajax({
            type:'POST',
            url:'{% url 'urlAjax' %}',
            data: formData,
            cache:false,
            contentType: false,
            processData: false,
            success: function (data) {
               alert("Success");
            }
        });
    });
```

Django views.py:

```
temp = request.POST.getlist('arr[]')
```

But it returns none.

Comment: You should check for `arr` parameter, not `arr[]`. Like this `temp = request.POST.getlist('arr')`

Comment: `formData.append('arr', arr);` .. Also its `,` not `:`

Comment: Also note that passing an array value to formData it will get stringified the same as using `join()`.

Comment: @krylov123 I have already tried that too.

Comment: @Mohamed-Yousef It didnot work.

Comment: Did you tried adding elements in explicit way? Like this: `var formData = new FormData(this);` `formData.append('arr[]', 'My');`  `formData.append('arr[]', 'Array');`

Answer (score 1):

ajax

```
formData.append('arr[]', '['+arr.toString()+']');
```

Django views.py:

```
import ast
    
temp = request.POST.get('arr[]')
arr = ast.literal_eval(temp)
```

you can use `ast`.